# How to get @FindAll working for InternetExplorer WebDriver with Selenium

Tags: css, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, findall

I am trying to run a TestNG Suite against Internet Explorer. However, it seems to be failing trying to find an element on the webpage using the CSS locator. I am using the @FindAll annotation to specify multiple locating strategies and these strategies work fine for Chrome and Firefox. Here is the error I am seeing in the TestNG failure summary:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:  (WARNING: The server did not
>   provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 70
>   milliseconds Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time:
>   '2016-03-15 17:00:58' System info: host: '(hostname was here-omitted)', ip:
>   '10.18.28.53', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver Capabilities
>   [{browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true,
>   enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false,
>   ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, version=11,
>   platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false,
>   elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=,
>   requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer,
>   initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:28843/, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}] Session ID:
>   3ccb2fc8-aac7-484c-8a0d-ca8c8539742e
>   *** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=#content > div.container > h1}   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:388)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:496)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElements(By.java:441)   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.ByAll.findElements(ByAll.java:63)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.ByAll.findElement(ByAll.java:52)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.getText(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.webcp.common.pageobjects.LoginPage.getLoginTextTop(LoginPage.java:58)
>     at
>   com.webcp.common.pageobjects.LoginPage.verifyLoginTextTop(LoginPage.java:65)
>     at
>   com.webcp.common.tests.LoginPageTest.verifyLoginPage(LoginPageTest.java:45)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)

And here is the code block that is running:

TestBaseSetup class snippet:

```
public class TestBaseSetup
    {
        private static WebDriver    driver;
        private static Logger       Log         = Logger.getLogger(TestBaseSetup.class.getName());
        static String               driverPath  = "C:\\Users\\bberndt\\eclipse\\Selenium Files\\";

        public static WebDriver getDriver()
            {
                return driver;
            }

private static WebDriver initIEDriver(String appURL)
        {
            Log.info("Launching Microsoft Internet Explorer with new profile");
            File file = new File(driverPath + "IEDriverServer.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
            WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            Log.info("Driver instantiated");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            Log.info("Window maximized");
            driver.get(appURL);
            Log.info("Navigating to: " + appURL);
            return driver;
        }
}
```

LoginPageTest Class:

```
public class LoginPageTest extends TestBaseSetup
{
    private WebDriver       driver;
    private LoginPage       loginPage;
    private HomePage        homePage;
    private SoftAssert      softAssert;
    private static Logger   Log = Logger.getLogger(LoginPageTest.class.getName());
    private String          sTestCaseName;
    private int             iTestCaseRow;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUpTest()
        {
            driver = getDriver();
            Log.info("Driver loaded");
            //loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
            loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
            homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage.class);
            softAssert = new SoftAssert();

        }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void verifyLoginPage()
        {
            Log.info("--------------------------START TEST---------------------------");
            Log.info("Test 1: verifyLoginPage");
            softAssert.assertTrue(loginPage.verifyLoginPageTitle(), "Login page title does not match\n");
            softAssert.assertTrue(loginPage.verifyLoginTextTop(), "Login text top does not match\n");
            softAssert.assertTrue(loginPage.verifyLoginTextBottom(), "Login text bottom does not match\n");
            softAssert.assertAll();
        }
}
```

LoginPage object Repository:

```
public class LoginPage
    {
        protected WebDriver     driver;
        private static Logger   Log = Logger.getLogger(LoginPage.class.getName());

        @FindAll({ @FindBy(xpath = "/html/body/div/div/div/h1"),
                @FindBy(css = "#content > div.container > h1") })
        private WebElement      loginTextTop;
        @FindAll({ @FindBy(xpath = "/html/body/div/div/div/h2"),
                @FindBy(css = "h2") })
        private WebElement      loginTextBottom;

        public LoginPage(WebDriver driver)
            {
                this.driver = driver;
            }

        public String getPageTitle()
            {
                String title = driver.getTitle();
                return title;
            }

        public boolean verifyLoginPageTitle()
            {
                String expectedPageTitle = "WTS";
                return getPageTitle().contains(expectedPageTitle);
            }

        public String getLoginTextTop()
            {
                String TextTop = loginTextTop.getText();
                return TextTop;
            }

        public boolean verifyLoginTextTop()
            {
                String expectedPageText = "Welcome to CenterPoint™";
                return getLoginTextTop().contains(expectedPageText);
            }

        public String getLoginTextBottom()
            {
                String TextBottom = loginTextBottom.getText();
                return TextBottom;
            }

        public boolean verifyLoginTextBottom()
            {
                String expectedPageText = "Please Sign In";
                return getLoginTextBottom().contains(expectedPageText);
            }
    }
```

Comment: What versions of Internet Explorer is this supposed to be running against?

Comment: The version I am using is IE 11 @Zoot

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this was not an issue with the code. Rather, there was a setting in Internet Options that needed to be turned on in order to make it work.
Advanced > Settings > Security > Allow active content to run in files on My Computer.

Once I checked this box, my IE test worked as expected.